# Getting "Assertion failed: (anonymous function)" on Safari with application

Tags: java, javascript, html, rest, safari

I am creating an application for an ipad and i am doing it using Java. JavaScript. HTML and Rest. I have a list of countries that i want to display in a drop list on one of the page in the application am im trying to use rest to populate this list but when i run the application i am getting nothing in the droplist and safari is giving the error

```
Assertion failed: (anonymous function) :449
```

i am gettin this error 8 times with different numbers at the end

here is some of the code that i am using

main.html

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="mainBackground">
     <div id="stflogo"><img src="images/logo.png" width="200" height="186" alt="MyLogo logo" /></div>

<div id="formContainer">
        <h1>Register Your Card</h1>
        <form id="AccountDetailsForm" method="post" data-ajax="false">

                <input  id="tfscCardNumber" type="hidden" name="tfscCardNumber" class="readonly" minlength="2" maxlength="20" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled"/>


                <p><label id="firstNameLabel" for="firstName" class="displayBlockLabel RequiredField">First Name </label>
                <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" class="required" minlength="2" maxlength="20"/></p>
                <p><label id="lastNameLabel" for="lastName" class="displayBlockLabel RequiredField"> Last Name </label>
                <input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName" class="required" minlength="2" maxlength="25"/></p>        

                <p><label id="address1Label" for="address1" class="displayBlockLabel RequiredField">Address 1 </label>
                <input id="address1" type="text" name="address1" class="required" minlength="2" maxlength="40"/></p>
                <p><label id="address2Label" for="address2" class="displayBlockLabel">Address 2</label>
                <input id="address2" type="text" name="address2" maxlength="40"/></p>

                <p><label id="cityLabel" for="city" class="displayBlockLabel RequiredField">Town / City </label>
                <input id="city" type="text" name="city" class="required" minlength="2" maxlength="40"/></p>

               <p> <label id="countyLabel" for="county" class="displayBlockLabel RequiredField">County / State </label>
                <input id="county" type="text" name="county" class="required" minlength="2" maxlength="40"/>    </p>

               <p> <label id="postcodeLabel" for="postcode" class="displayBlockLabel RequiredField">Postcode / Zip </label>
                <input id="postcode" type="text" name="postcode" class="required" minlength="2" maxlength="11"/>    </p>                

               <p> <label id="countrySelectionLabel" for="countrySelection" class="displayBlockLabel RequiredField">Country </label>
                <select id="countrySelection" class="required">
                </select> </p>

               <p><label id="telephoneLabel" for="telephone" class="displayBlockLabel RequiredField">Tel Number </label>
                <input id="telephone" type="tel" name="telephone" class="tel number required" minlength="2" maxlength="12"/></p>    
                <p><label id="emailLabel" for="email" class="displayBlockLabel RequiredField">Email </label>
                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="email required" minlength="2" maxlength="100"/></p>                                      
                <p><label id="confirmEmailLabel" for="confirmEmail" class="displayBlockLabel RequiredField">Confirm Email </label>
                <input id="confirmEmail" type="email" name="confirmEmail" class="email required" minlength="5" maxlength="100"/></p>    

                <p><label id="passportNumberLabel" for="passportNumber" class="displayBlockLabel RequiredField">Passport Number </label>
                <input id="passportNumber" type="text" name="passportNumber" class="required" minlength="3" maxlength="20"/></p>        
                <p class="tandcnotice">Please Ensure that you have read the Terms &amp; Conditions and Privacy &amp; security Policy</p>

                <p class="tandcCheckbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="accepttandc" id="accepttandc" class="checkbox" />
                <label for="checkbox" class="accepttandc">I have read the Terms &amp; Conditions</label>
                <p>

                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" data-role="button" data-theme="redbutton"/>
        </form>
     </div><!-- END OF FORM CONTAINER -->
     </div>
</div>
....
```

appForm.js

```
$('#wrapper').live("pageshow", function() {
if ( $('#countrySelection')[0].length < 1){

    $.mobile.loadingMessage = "Retrieving Countries";
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

    Repository.load('details/countries/all', function(countries){
        $.each(countries, function() {
            $('#countrySelection').append('<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.name + '</option>').selectmenu('refresh');
        });
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    });
}

});


$('#wrapper').live("pagecreate", function() {               

$('#AccountDetailsForm select, #AccountDetailsForm input[type!=submit]').focus(function (){
    focusScroller(this);                                                                                   
});
$('#AccountDetailsForm select, #AccountDetailsForm input[type!=submit]').blur(function (){
    if ( $('#accountFormScrollView').data().scrolllistview._sy < $('#accountFormScrollView').data().scrolllistview._maxY){
         $('#accountFormScrollView').data().scrolllistview.scrollTo(0, $('#accountFormScrollView').data().scrolllistview._maxY, 0);
    }
}); 

});           


$(window).resize(function (){
// Android Resize Event needed for the keyboard
});

var focusScroller = function(formElement){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    var elementLabel = "#" + formElement.id + "Label";   
    var offSetPosition = $(elementLabel)[0].offsetTop;
    if(formElement.labels === undefined && formElement.id === "countrySelection"){
        // ios4 quirk for select elements
        offSetPosition = 100; 
    }

    scrollTo(0,0,0);
    $('#accountFormScrollView').data().scrolllistview.scrollTo(0, offSetPosition * -1, 0);
}


$('#wrapper"').live("pageshow", function() {
if (getTfscCardNumber() === ''){
    $('#passportNumberLabel').css('display', 'none');
    $('#passportNumber').css('display', 'none'); 
    $('#passportNumber').attr("disabled", true);
}else{
    $('#passportNumberLabel').css('display', 'block');
    $('#passportNumber').css('display', 'block'); 
    $('#passportNumber').attr("disabled", false);
}

loadForm($('#AccountDetailsForm')[0]);
});
```

i can put up more code if needed but im sure the rest of the code is ok but if anyone wants to look at any other pieces of code just ask

what does this error mean and can anyone see what is going wrong?

Comment: I think it means you have an error in line number 449

Comment: i dont think so because none of my classes have 449 lines of code in them so that cant be right

Comment: It could be from a library you are using. If you could run this on a Desktop you could use the built in debugging tools in your browser to get more information but on an iPad I dont think those are available...

Comment: ya i am currently running on my desktop and im using firefox and safari to test it

Comment: Try running this in Chrome Inspector, click on the Scripts tab and click the stop sign in the bottom left corner until it glows purple - that will halt on the exception thrown and you can see the call stack. This is happening on a self-executing function so it will be hard to pinpoint unless you debug right when the exception is caught.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug with Safari and its handling of inputs with type="tel". I wouldn't worry about it.

I was having the same problem and then I found this: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2341

Comment: cheers :) i was ignoring it alright as it was not effecting my application but it was still annoying me why this was happeneing